# xStream XML into ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Yes, I"ve read and re-read the codehause tutorials but can't seem to pinpoint what's wrong. I suspect it may have to do with a custom converter but want some clarity before I shoot in the dark.

I have an object with String members and two List members I get from a WSDL jar file. I read the XML {`xstream.fromXML(MYFILE)`} then cast to my ArrayList to return. That works well but my issue is that instead of listMember1 and listMember2 being set to their respective arrays, listMember1 is set to a concat of (listMember1 + listMember2) and listMember2 remains null.

Ever seen this before?? I'm out of ideas... thx

Here is some XML:

```
<root>
 <VCon>
    <Role>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Role>
    <Role>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Role>
    <Role>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Role>
    <Method>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Method>
    <Method>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Method>
 </VCon>
 <VCon>
    <Role>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Role>
    <Role>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Role>
    <Role>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Role>
    <Method>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Method>
    <Method>
      <fname>steve</fname>
      <lname>jobs</lname>
    </Method>
 </VCon>
</root>
```

Here is code for my xStream aliases:

```
xstream.alias("listMember1", Role.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(VCon.class, "listMember1");

xstream.alias("listMember2", Method.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(VCon.class, "listMember2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble is in your xml structure. 
Try to put a attribut on Vcon balise. Or you have to add a balise in order to discriminate exactly each lists.

See you later.

Yann